# How to show data in rows with relation condition using Angular 8 iterating ngFor inside another ngFor?

Tags: html, html-table, angular8

I need to display data in a table from API json response with 2 arrays. 1st table row with 1st array and 2nd table with 2nd array data only when there is a common value in array 1 and 2.

Array 1 data
Array 2 data
Array 1 data
Array 2 data
Array 1 data
Array 2 data

like this ^.

Any idea or suggestion ?

I tried ngIf condition but it didn't work. :( maybe I am not using it in the proper way.

Comment: We have to use <ng-container> to run the outer ngFor then its working.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.